# Selenium in Python Error Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, staleelementreferenceexception

[image]

Hello, I'm using Selenium with python and am getting the error in the title and I'm really at a loss to why.

It seems to be this that is causing the issue:

```
down_arrow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember68"]/span')
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ember68"]/span')))
time.sleep(2)
down_arrow.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

The weird thing is that the page does actually click the right button and opens but then none of the rest of the code will run.

Can anybody help?

UPDATE: I have tried `down_arrow = WebDriverWait(driver, 10,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember68"]/span')))` and get the same error from that line.

Okay, even though it is executing the lines I wrote above, the error can actually be traced back from to before those lines:

```
search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

for i in range(0, len(company_name)):
    search_query.send_keys('"linkedin" AND ' + '"{}"'.format(company_name[i]))
```

I think this is actually what is giving the error ^

Comment: Can you try putting the line >> " search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q') " << inside the _for_ loop? Like this:

Comment: for i in range(0, len(company_name)):
    search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search_query.send_keys('"linkedin" AND ' + '"{}"'.format(company_name[i]))

Comment: Also, just to be sure, can you add the line below and tell us what happens, please --->>
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(search_query))